# JavaScript 8.0 shall not be displayed as 8

Tags: javascript

I want to display value of integer variable as 8.0 , but the output show only 8

```
var c = 8.0;
console.log(c);
```

**Output:** `8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use toFixed

```
console.log(c.toFixed(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display it with the decimal you can use var c = 8.0; **c.toFixed(1)** which would output **8.0**